# Create files with similar names using Java without overwriting existing file

Tags: java

I was wondering if it is possible to create multiple files with similar names, without overwriting the current file.

for example: 
if I have a file: xyz.txt
next time when i create it should be : xyz(1).txt

```
try {
  File makefile = new File("output.txt");
  FileWriter fwrite = new FileWriter(makefile);
  fwrite.write("example file");
  fwrite.flush();
  fwrite.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

so if I re-run this program my current file should not be overwritten. I have already tried and if condition with a flag variable to add number as prefix to the file name.

I want to know if there are any Java commands to avoid overwriting an existing file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to know if there are any native java commands to stop overwriting [and append a numeral to the filename]

Not in the core Java libraries, no.

Comment: ha ha guess i will use the same then :)

Answer (score 4):

Not in java as already indicated by `@Greg Kopff`.
But you can work around something like this:

```
  int count = 0;

  public void createFile(String name) throws IOException
  {
    File f;
    f = new File(name);
    if (!f.exists())
    {
      f.createNewFile();
    }
    else
    {
      count++;
      createFile(name + (count));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have done this already. have mentioned it in my post but thanks for the reply :)

Comment: If that is the case then you're on the right track - You need to tell java not to replace the existing file - else java will by default truncate the file to empty and replace it with current value submitted to it.

Comment: This solution is not thread-safe, we should rely the return flag of createNewFile() instead, as createNewFile() would create the file atomically and returns false if file already existed.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the method [File.createTempFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29)

> To create the new file, the prefix and the suffix may first be adjusted to fit the limitations of the underlying platform. If the prefix is too long then it will be truncated, but its first three characters will always be preserved. If the suffix is too long then it too will be truncated, but if it begins with a period character ('.') then the period and the first three characters following it will always be preserved. Once these adjustments have been made the name of the new file will be generated by concatenating the prefix, ***five or more internally-generated characters***, and the suffix.

Comment: @Greg Kopff - There is an overloaded method which takes a directory as one of the argument which allows you to create files in the specified directory instead of defaulting to temp always.

Comment: +1: This is the most appropriate way to do it. If you pass in the directory to the method it will store where you tell it to. As long as you dont use the `deleteOnExit()` method, the files wont be deleted. Also, you have written `createTimeFile()` instead of `createTempFile()` :)

Comment: @Deco - Thanks for catching the typo

Answer (score 2):

While similar to Bitmap's response, I came up with this java code (which seems to work). I don't know if it's the most efficient, but...

For my example, I am assuming the file will be a .txt file

```
String fileName = "output.txt"; 
File aFile = new File(fileName);

int fileNo = 0;
while(aFile.exists() && !aFile.isDirectory()) { 
    fileNo++; 
    String newName = fileName.replaceAll(".txt", "(" + fileNo + ").txt");   
    aFile = new File(newName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For kotlin**

Here is the code for create files with similar names using Kotlin without overwriting existing file:

```
var fileNo = 0

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun createFile(name: String, addedEx: String): File {
    val originalName = name.replace(addedEx,"")
    val f = File(name)
    return if (!f.exists()) {
        f
    } else {
        fileNo++
        val file = createFile("${name.substring( 0, originalName.indexOf("."))}_($fileNo).${getExtension(originalName)}","_($fileNo)")
        fileNo = 0
        file
    }
}
```

Remember when you call it for the first time just pass empty string in `addedEx` param. Like this : `createFile(nameTest.txt, addedEx: "")`

if save this file 5 times then,
**Output will be:**

> nameTest.txt
>
> nameTest_(1).txt
>
> nameTest_(2).txt
>
> nameTest_(3).txt
>
> nameTest_(4).txt

if you want's the extension getting function:

```
fun getExtension(name: String?): String? {
    val fileNameFromURL = Uri.parse(name).lastPathSegment
    if(fileNameFromURL != null && fileNameFromURL.lastIndexOf('.') >= 0)
    {
        return fileNameFromURL.substring(fileNameFromURL.lastIndexOf('.')+1)
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static String getUniquePath(String path,String extension){
        int i = 1;
        String newPath = path + extension;
        if(new File(newPath).exists()) {
            while (new File(newPath).exists()){
                newPath = path + "_" + i + extension;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return newPath;
    }
```