# how can create multiple files with same name in the same directory using java?

Tags: java, file, directory

As per my requirement,i need to upload a file into a specified directory,later after some modifications, i need to upload the same file into the same directory,here previous file should not be overridden means files must be saved in the same directory with same names(here i have one assumption,that , for example if my file is abc.txt, after modifications if i upload the modified file it can be saved as abc(1).txt  ). how can i resolve my issue? can anybody assist me to come out from this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Create files with similar names using Java without overwriting existing file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295100/create-files-with-similar-names-using-java-without-overwriting-existing-file)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`File.createNewFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) in a while loop. It will create the file if and only if the file does not exist. This is thread-safe, since the API guarantees atomicity.

Checking the existence of the file with [`File.exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) in a loop does not give you such guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

if you can persist the number of uploads you could increment a number for each particular file and attend it to your filename (e.g. foo_1.txt or however you want)
if you can't you might wanna go through all your files and check if they fit your naming schema. then you can extract the highest number, increment it by 1 and append it to your new file.

Answer (score 0):

check the methods of [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) like:

[exists()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)

if the file is existing you can count a number and create a new file name like

```
newFilename = MessageFormat.format("({0}){1}", counter++, originalFilename);
File newFile = new File(originalFile.getParentFile(),newFilename);
```

You can create and check new files as long as you find a filename which is not existing.