# Rename file like "name+index"

Tags: java, file, rename

Is there a way in Java to create a file and rename it if that file already exists, e.g. "Dog.jpg", to something like that "Dog(1).jpg" and so on ("Dog(2).jpg" if "Dog(1).jpg" exists too, etc.)?

Comment: Yes. First search if the file exists, if it does, iteratively search if Dog(i).jpg exists and when it finally doesn't, create it.

Comment: Try what @RoneRackal said, post if you run into issues with the code. Asking for the entire code here isn't right.

Comment: this might be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828451/how-can-create-multiple-files-with-same-name-in-the-same-directory-using-java/10828566#10828566

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create files with similar names using Java without overwriting existing file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295100/create-files-with-similar-names-using-java-without-overwriting-existing-file)

Comment: It is a bit tricky to get this concurrency-proof (if that is a concern).

Comment: Problem solved!!! Ty so much for all the answers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File` class in java has a method called [`exists`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) use that to check if the file exists or not

If it does exist rename it to something else.

Repeat this process until you find a file name that does not exsist

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way to create a file but name it something different if it already exists. Have you taken a look at the [javadocs for the `File` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)? Specifically, the `exists()` method. If that returns true, try creating a "Dog(1).jpg", if call `exists()` again. etc.